Underlying mechanism for black body radiation
I understand that every body of some temperature above the absolute zero radiates EM waves. When we heat it up enough it enters the visible spectrum and than proceeds to go upwards to higher and higher energies.
But why would matter radiate EM waves in the first place ? What is the underlying mechanism for such a phenomenon?
Addendum:
I am also interested when this radiation stops. I know that I am now radiating infrared radiation. A block of $1$ by $1$ m solid material  would also radiate EM proportional to its temperature. If we slice it in half, also. But what if we take a really small chunk of it (one or a couple of atoms)? Would it still radiate EM waves? Since temperature is only defined for a system of a large number of particles how would it radiate proportional to its temperature since temperature is ill defined on such small scales?

This question is similar to: What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Imagine a hot dark room (no photons) with black walls. The room is black, meaning it has the potential to absorb light in any frequency and thus it could theoretically also emit light in any frequency (the same energy levels that allow absorption allow emissions). Now because the room is hot, some atoms are in the excited levels, meaning they will emit light eventually. This light will get reabsorbed in the walls and in the steady state there will be some light and some excited atoms, that's the equilibrium in black body radiation

@JohnRennie I agree with you that this Q&A you have referred to subsumes this question but the answers and the question itself  there are on quite different level compared to this one and I think User198 would expect something along the lines of Ofek Gillon's comment above.
